# Unable to Execute Drools Programme in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, drools

I have written Drools and caller programme and have Junit which works fine.
But when I deploy to Tomcat 7 I run the application I find this issue as shown below:-

Exception in thread "pool-7-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(Ljava/net/URL;)Ljava/lang/
Object;
        at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl$kModuleMarshaller.fromXML(KieModuleModelImpl.java:190)
        at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl.fromXML(KieModuleModelImpl.java:139)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:163)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:125)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.discoverKieModules(ClasspathKieProject.java:96)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.init(ClasspathKieProject.java:68)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.(KieContainerImpl.java:83)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:85)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:68)
        at com.hm.msp.rules.service.DroolsRuleLoader.loadRules(DroolsRuleLoader.java:35)
        at com.hm.msp.workflow.service.task.TemperatureTasks.execute(TemperatureTasks.java:40)
        at com.hm.msp.workflow.service.flow.WorkFlowServiceCommunicator.executeEachOfItsTasks(WorkFlowServiceCommunicator.java:90)
        at com.hm.msp.workflow.service.flow.WorkFlowServiceCommunicator.execute(WorkFlowServiceCommunicator.java:65)
        at com.hm.msp.controller.service.TaskExecutor.run(TaskExecutor.java:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

---

Please assist

Answer (score 1):

The simple solutions in although the Drools pom contains the xstream jar, Still we have to declare in the pom Xstream.

The Dependency should be

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding below pom entry solved this error:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
```